# C# dynamic checkbox "checked"

Tags: c#, excel

I have a for loop to send 5 dynamically created textboxes to a row in Excel. This function works perfect but...I also have a checkbox that is created with each row and is currently ignored. I want to add this checkbox to my function. I only want the dynamic rows that have the checkbox selected to go to Excel. Below is my existing for loop code. This is the name of the checkbox (""chkAddItem")

```
 for (int CheckRow = 0; CheckRow < addOnRows; CheckRow++)
        {                                                   //add addOn rows to spreadsheet
            worksheet.Rows[StartAddOn].Insert();
            worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "D"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtQtyAddOn" + CheckRow].Text;
            worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "E"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProductNameAddOn" + CheckRow].Text;
            worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "F"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtListPriceAddOn" + CheckRow].Text;
            worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "G"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountAddOn" + CheckRow].Text;
            worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn++, "H"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceAddOn" + CheckRow].Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
for (int checkRow = 0; checkRow < addOnRows; checkRow++)
{      
   if (((CheckBox)srcAddOnPanel.Controls["chkAddItem" + checkRow]).Checked)
   {                                     
      //add addOn rows to spreadsheet
      worksheet.Rows[StartAddOn].Insert();
      worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "D"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtQtyAddOn" + checkRow].Text;
      worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "E"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProductNameAddOn" + checkRow].Text;
      worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "F"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtListPriceAddOn" + checkRow].Text;
      worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn, "G"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountAddOn" + checkRow].Text;
      worksheet.Cells[StartAddOn++, "H"].value = srcAddOnPanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceAddOn" + checkRow].Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep ! you are freakin' awesome,, thank you. I was forgetting the (((Checkbox) part